# Jersey Deserialization Json error - Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value

Tags: json, jersey, jackson

This is my DateDeserializer class :

```
public class DateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> 
{
     private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    public DateDeserializer()
    {
        this(null);
    }

    public DateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String date = arg0.getText();

        try
        {
            return formatter.parse(date);
        }
        catch(ParseException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I annotate the setter (appears also in getter method) of the Date attribute in my entity :

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class, as = Date.class)
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

When I send request in json format , the date has the format like in the deserializer method, but I get the following error :

"Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value"

Should I inject the deserializer to jersey somewhere ? 
I don't understand what I do wrong.

Here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

      <!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use JavaConfigWebApplicationContext
         instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

        <!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
         fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.sharon.trempiada.resources.ResourcesConfiguration org.sharon.trempiada.services.ServicesConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>trempiada</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.sharon.trempiada.resources,org.glassfish.jersey.jackson</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>trempiada</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My model class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBRIDES")
public class Ride 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name= "ride_id")
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String source;

    @Column
    private String destination;

    @Column
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
    private Date date;

    @Column
    private Time time;

    @Column
    private boolean isPermanent;

    @Column
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializer.class)
    private Date expirationDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="driver_id", nullable= false)
    private User user;

    @Column
    private String comments;


    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }
    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }
    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public Time getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(Time time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
    public boolean isPermanent() {
        return isPermanent;
    }
    public void setPermanent(boolean isPermanent) {
        this.isPermanent = isPermanent;
    }

    public Date getExpirationDate() {
        return expirationDate;
    }

    public void setExpirationDate(Date expirationDate) {
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }
    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

Comment: Print arg0.getText() and see the format

Comment: It doesn't even enter my DateDeserializer.deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1) method. Already put there a breakpoint

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Please add the complete model (not just the setter) and an executable example running your code and producing your exception. Also, as mentioned, add your complete stacktrace

Comment: Might the problem occur as I configured in the web.xml the PojoMapping feature which is an old one ?